# Swift: strange behavior about unwrapping

Tags: swift, ios8

In my Child model, I have declared the following properties:

```
var name:String?
var year:String?
var make:String?
var model:String?
```

and the init:

```
init(name:String, ... ,year:String, make:String, model:String, ...){
    self.name = name
    ...
    self.year = year
    self.make = make
    self.model = model
}
```

Here I construct a child:

```
Child(name:cName,...,year:cYear,make:cMake, model:cModel,...)
```

In

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!{
```

For the child's name I could use it directly without unwrapping:

```
cell!.textLabel.text = child.name
```

**But I have to unwrap child.year, child.make, child.model if I want to use them. Why is that?**

```
cell!.detailTextLabel.text = child.year! + " " + child.make! + " " + child.model!
```

I followed this [tutorial](http://jamesonquave.com/blog/developing-ios-8-apps-using-swift-interaction-with-multiple-views/) and build the project successfully. In that project, in a similar situation, I don't need to do unwrapping. [Code](https://github.com/jquave/Swift-Tutorial/blob/Part6/SwiftTutorial/SearchResultsViewController.swift)

```
cell.text = album.title
cell.image = UIImage(named: "Blank52")
cell.detailTextLabel.text = album.price
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an explicit unwrap because you are using concatenation operator. Concatenation is not defined for optional strings, so you need to add exclamation point to unwrap the values. You should be able to avoid it if you use string interpolation, like this:

```
cell!.detailTextLabel.text = "\(child.year) \(child.make) \(child.model)"
```

Note: if the initializer that you show is the only one available, you should be able to make your strings non-optional.

Comment: Thanks! That make sense. Is this point included in the documentation

Comment: @fuiiii I doubt that it's in the docs now, but it's definitely worth being included.

Comment: How do you know about it then?

Comment: @fuiiii I read about the concatenation operator, and saw that the doc does not mention optional strings. If the operator were defined for optionals, the docs would have mentioned that, because enabling concatenation for optionals requires additional compiler work.

Comment: I see. Thanks! This makes much sense!

Comment: The most important part of this answer is the buried lede: your mistake was declaring `name:String?` (etc.) in the first place. Since you are going to set those properties in the initializer, you should definitely not do that; you should declare them as simple values, e.g. `name:String`. This is legal (not optional, but no default value either) _because_ you will set them in the initializer. And then all your problems will vanish in a puff of smoke!