# What patterns cause the Swift compiler to panic / halt and catch fire?

Tags: xcode, swift

XCode 6, Beta 4

I keep running into new cases where the swift compiler consumes all CPU and RAM resources.  Is there a list of known cases / code patterns to avoid?

So far, I have lost far too much time to tracking down these statements:

**Longer arithmetic expressions that use array operators**

> let f = n1*n3*t*t*t + (n1*n3*t*t*t / n1*n2*t*t) + bx[1]  // (rapid memory leak, OS freezes)

Note that long expressions that do not use the array operators do not suffer the same plight, this works just fine:

> let e = n1*n3*t*t*t + (n1*n3*t*t*t / n1*n2*t*t) + n1*n2*t*t + n2*n3*t + n2*bx3 + 2.0 * n3

**Assignment from ternary operators and/or arithmetic expressions:**

> ```
> var mx = useCurrent // (SourceKit process consumes available CPU capacity 500%+)
>       ? (nextPt.x - curPt.x) * 0.5 + (curPt.x - prevPt.x)*0.5
>       : (nextPt.x - curPt.x) * 0.5
> ```

I have found this, but no comprehensive list:

- [Swift: unwrapping cause swift compile slowly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24842995/swift-unwrapping-cause-swift-compile-slowly/24843217#comment38680841_24843217) (this one may actually be the arithmetic, like above, and not the unwrapping)

So: is there a list of known code syntax / patterns to avoid?

Comment: Some useful discussion here: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/228267?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Note that the two postings you cite are about two completely different things. One is the indexing crash-and-burn; the mere presence of certain code causes you to lose control of the computer. The other is just a slow compilation.

Comment: I think this question has some potential. But you need to get rid of *"...is there a list of..."*. That's a reason to close, and its likely to keep the question from being re-opened. Then, ask a concise question.

Comment: @jww: Thanks, but what would you suggest?  I have tried multiple forms.