# How to track down slow compiling Swift code?

Tags: xcode, swift, compilation

Xcode has added a great feature to see your application compile in real time but how can you see compile durations for individual classes and then further see what code is causing the slow compile times?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25537614/155513) is helpful but only gets part way there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [xctool](https://github.com/facebook/xctool).  When you compile your project on the command line it will emit the time taken to compile each file to the console.  e.g:

`✓ Compile MySwiftFile.swift (12067 ms)`

Additionally, for Swift 1.2 at least there is a flag `debug-time-function` which can be passed to the Swift compiler to show you problematic *functions*.

Further discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31520133/output-compile-durations-for-swift-files)

Answer (score 3):

Swift now includes a function-by-function compiler profiler. You can enable it with the compiler flag `-Xfrontend -debug-time-function-bodies`.

Run a clean rebuild and use the `grep` command from [this post](http://irace.me/swift-profiling) to get a reverse-sorted list of compile time by function.

This was hugely helpful for me - I trimmed maybe 15 seconds off my build time by tuning the slowest-to-compile functions.

Answer (score 1):

Open the Report navigator (Balloon icon left pane). When you build click the top most line with the build hammer and you see the compilation progress for each compiled file.

Comment: That seems helpful for _really_ slow compiling files but since Xcode compiles many files in parallel and none of my files are high multi-second compiles I can't visually see which files take the longest as it happens too fast.  Ideally there would be a way to actually see the time of each file's compiling

Comment: The swift compiler has a `-j <n>` option to control the # of parallel compiles. Maybe if you supply that to 1 you can watch it better.

Comment: I just tried that. It seems that swift does not go ahead so much when providing the option but still queues a couple of files for compilation. My class files are rather tiny so it just goes plop, plop, plop ,..