# Output compile durations for swift files

Tags: swift, xcode, compiler-optimization, compilation-time

Is there a way to output the time taken to compile a swift file during an xcode build?

I would like to compile from the command line to trigger the same build xcode does but to include the time taken to compile each file.

The `Report Navigator` show full build reports per file but there is no timeframe associated with them.

I would like to cut down the compile time of a Swift 1.2 project, as it takes around 5 - 10 minutes after a clean or 3 -5 minutes after changing source in a heavily dependent file.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can add…

```
-Xfrontend -debug-time-function-bodies
```

…to *Other Swift Flags in Swift Compiler - Custom Flags* section (build settings).

[image: Build settings]

Note: You have to keep same order of these flags. `-Xfrontend` says that the next flag should be passed to the frontend. It will not work if you reverse the order.

Then you can get compile times in your build log:

[image: Build log]

Which is useful when you do want to optimize compile time and also it's good to attach this kind of build log when reporting an issue to [Apple Swift guys](http://bugreport.apple.com) about slow compile time.

Credit goes to [Joe Pamer](https://twitter.com/jopamer/status/589231512106569728) *Errant compiler hacker. Currently an engineering manager at Apple (Swift, Clang), formerly at Microsoft (TypeScript, F#, JavaScript, .NET).* He tweeted it as a response to Rob Rix question about profiling Swift compilation. It made me curious, so, I disassembled compiler, checked text section for more flags and found [other hidden options](https://github.com/robertvojta/robertvojta.github.io/blob/master/_posts/2015-06-30-swift-hidden-options.md). Don't use them in production code, just play with them.

---

Build time of the whole project. Run following command in terminal…

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode ShowBuildOperationDuration YES
```

…restart Xcode, clean & build and…

[image: Build time]

---

### What if I have pods?

Do same as above for your **pods** project

Comment: Thanks. After scanning through compile logs of about 5 classes it gets difficult to manage. Is there a way to output the total time per file?

Comment: Updated my answer with description how to measure whole project build time (unsupported feature, can break in any future version). Checking if there's a way how to measure single file.

Comment: To close the case, there's no switch or plist setting to output compile time per file. Or I didn't find it. Maybe you can wrap swift[c] with some shell script to measure it (didn't try).

Comment: Travis CI does show the compile time per file! i guess they use the facebook xbuild tool

Comment: Other hidden options link seems to be broken

Comment: Sry, I didn't migrate my old posts to Medium (yet). Here's the link to the repo with post: https://github.com/robertvojta/robertvojta.github.io/blob/master/_posts/2015-06-30-swift-hidden-options.md

Comment: Try to use this: `xcodebuild -workspace App.xcworkspace -scheme App clean build OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS="-Xfrontend -debug-time-function-bodies" | grep .[0-9]ms | grep -v ^0.[0-9]ms | sort -nr > culprits.txt` (Source: http://irace.me/swift-profiling)

Comment: You said "You have to keep same order of these flags.", what flag order are you talking about? I only see one flag here `-debug-time-function-bodies`.