# What is the difference between Type Safety and Type Inference?

Tags: swift, optimization, type-inference, type-safety, compilation-time

How are they different? I get a bit confused because they seem to be similar concepts.

How does understanding them help with optimizing compilation time?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

From Swift's own [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID322):

### Type Safety

Swift is a type-safe language. A type safe language encourages you to be clear about the types of values your code can work with. *If part of your code expects a String, you can’t pass it an Int by mistake.*

```
var welcomeMessage: String
welcomeMessage = 22 // this would create an error because you  
//already specified that it's going to be a String
```

### Type Inference

If you **don’t** specify the type of value you need, Swift uses type inference to work out the appropriate type. Type inference enables a compiler *to deduce the type of a particular expression automatically when it compiles your code*, simply by examining the values you provide.

```
var meaningOfLife = 42 // meaningOfLife is inferred to be of type Int
meaningOfLife = 55 // it Works, because 55 is an Int
```

**Type Safety & Type Inference together**

```
var meaningOfLife = 42 // 'Type inference' happened here, we didn't specify that this an Int, the compiler itself found out.
meaningOfLife = 55 // it Works, because 55 is an Int
meaningOfLife = "SomeString" // Because of 'Type Safety' ability you will get an 
//error message: 'cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'Int''
```

---

### Tricky example for protocols with associated types:

Imagine the following protocol

```
protocol Identifiable {
    associatedtype ID
    var id: ID { get set }

}
```

You would adopt it like this:

```
struct Person: Identifiable {
    typealias ID = String
    var id: String
}
```

However you can also adopt it like this:

```
struct Website: Identifiable {
    var id: URL
}
```

You can remove the `typealias`. The compiler will still infer the type.

For more see [Generics - Associated Types](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html)

> Thanks to Swift’s type inference, you don’t actually need to declare a
> concrete Item of Int as part of the definition of IntStack. Because
> IntStack conforms to all of the requirements of the Container
> protocol, Swift can infer the appropriate Item to use, simply by
> looking at the type of the append(_:) method’s item parameter and the
> return type of the subscript. Indeed, if you delete the typealias Item
> = Int line from the code above, everything still works, because it’s clear what type should be used for Item.

### Type-safety and Generics

Suppose you have the following code:

```
struct Helper<T: Numeric> {
    func adder(_ num1: T, _ num2: T) -> T {
        return num1 + num2
    }
    var num: T
}
```

`T` can be anything that's numeric e.g. `Int`, `Double`, `Int64`, etc.

However as soon as you type `let h = Helper(num: 10)` the compiler will assume that `T` is an `Int`. It won't accept `Double`, `Int64`, for its `adder` func anymore. It will only accept `Int`.

This is again because of type-inference and type-safety.

- type-inference: because it has to infer that that the *generic* is of type `Int`.
- type-safety: because once the `T` is set to be of type `Int`, it will no longer accept `Int64`, `Double`...

As you can see in the screenshot the signature is now changed to only accept a parameter of type `Int`
[image]

## Pro tip to optimize compiler performance:

The less type inference your code has to do the faster it compiles. Hence it's recommended to avoid collection literals. And the longer a collection gets, the slower its type inference becomes...

**not bad**

```
let names = ["John", "Ali", "Jane", " Taika"]
```

**good**

```
let names : [String] = ["John", "Ali", "Jane", " Taika"]
```

For more see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29707622/swift-compiler-error-expression-too-complex-on-a-string-concatenation/39514629#39514629).

Also see [Why is Swift compile time so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25833188/5175709)

The solution helped his compilation time go down from 10/15 seconds to a single second.