# difference between var someVar:[String] = [] and var someVar =[String]()

Tags: swift

```
var someVar:[String] = [] 

var someVar = [String]()
```

What is the difference beetween this?

Comment: with the first option you have **type safety** with the 2nd one you have **type inference**. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37707403/what-is-the-difference-between-type-safety-and-type-inference/37707404#37707404)

Comment: Nevertheless in most cases you should trust the compiler (inference) more than yourself (safety) ;-)