# Speed up Xcode Swift build times

Tags: swift, xcode, compiler-optimization, compile-time

As my project has grown over the past year, so have its build times. Over the last few months it's gone from 4 minutes to around 7 (time includes GitHub pull, unit tests, etc).

I have investigated with `-Xfrontend -debug-time-function-bodies` to find lines that are slow to compile, and changed that code.

I believe it's now a question of project size; 182 Swift files, ≈31K lines. 23 storyboards, 52 XIBs. This is a regular UIKit app with a handful of Cocoapods dependencies.

The bulk of the build time is spent in the "Compiling Swift source files" phase.

The build machine time I care less about than the edit-build-debug cycle, which has also been slowing.

What can be done to improve build times?

Comment: Factor some code out into frameworks. Those don't have to get compiled every time you change something.

Comment: Have you tried without xibs? I built a project in Swift 1.x with no xibs and  no obvious difference in compile times, but I've since joined a company where there are xibs everywhere, so haven't had chance to test this out with a large project.

Comment: Physical hardware plays a big part too, a Mac with a fast SSD and a lot of physical threads will crunch through Swift source files.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an article about benchmarking/speeding up compilation time - [swift-profiling](http://irace.me/swift-profiling).

In case it goes dead here is the tldr:

```
xcodebuild -workspace App.xcworkspace -scheme App clean build OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS="-Xfrontend -debug-time-function-bodies" | grep .[0-9]ms | grep -v ^0.[0-9]ms | sort -nr > culprits.txt
```

You can just run that or add the following flags to your build under the other-swift-flags in build settings:

```
-Xfrontend -warn-long-function-bodies=100
```

This will show you which lines are slowing down your compile time.

Comment: @ricardopereira I don't see why it wouldn't. Let me know if it doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

Xcode 8.1/Swift 3.1 adds some relief for projects including some ObjC. Precompiled headers are back! https://swift.org/blog/bridging-pch/

If your project includes a bridging header, this will help. (In Xcode 8.1 beta 4 and later, this is the default; in prior betas add `-enable-bridging-pch` to `Other Swift Flags`).

Answer (score 3):

Turning on the **`Whole Module Optimization`** while adding **`-Onone`** in **`Other Swift Flags`** worked for me, it reduced compilation time to 3 minutes from 10.
Read more here - [Speed Up Swift Compilation](http://developear.com/blog/2016/12/30/Speed-Swift-Compilation.html)

I'm using **`Swift 3` on `Xcode 8.3`**.

Comment: I'm amazed. My build went from 68s to 52s. Xcode bug? Debugging still works fine.

Comment: I opened Radar 31539545 to ask Apple if there are negative repurcussions, and if not, could this become Xcode's default.

Comment: Hi what does the -Onone flag do ? Thank you.

Comment: `-Onone` tells the compiler not to optimize anything, leaving it in a more easily debuggable state.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this great post: 
https://github.com/fastred/Optimizing-Swift-Build-Times

Some contents included:

- Type checking of functions and expressions
- Slowly compiling files
- Build active architecture only
- dSYM generation
- Whole Module Optimization
- Third-party dependencies
- Modularization
- XIBs
- Xcode Schemes
- Use the new Xcode build system
- Enable concurrent Swift build tasks
- Showing build times in Xcode

Answer (score -1):

**Since Xcode 9.3** there is a `Compilation Mode` called `Single File`. It's explicitly said that it can change a game when talking about compilation times in the Xcode release notes

> The choice for compiling Swift code by file or by module moved from
> the Optimization Level setting to Compilation Mode, which is a new
> setting for the Swift compiler in the Build Settings pane of the
> Project editor. Previously this choice was combined with others in the
> Optimization Level setting. Compiling by file enables building only
> the files that changed, enabling faster builds. Compiling by module
> enables better optimization.

It truly is a life saver. My incremental compilation times for enterprise project was decreased to couple of seconds. You can try it.

[image]

**EDIT: In Xcode 12, the same can be referred as Incremental**