# Adding swift to my objective C App is making some functionalities very slow

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

I have a a small swift App that works fine, i needed to add it and use it in my Objective-C new application, the integration part was ok and the App works fine, but one of the view controllers takes too much time when loaded and i can't figure out why, i tried using the following:

- Build Time Analyzer for Xcode(but it didn't work since my project was
  an objective-C project.
- tried referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25537614/why-is-swift-compile-time-so-slow)

Nothing seems to work, any help?

Comment: Did you profile your app using Instruments?

Comment: what do u mean by instruments?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/index.html

Comment: yes i have and nothing is showing on any of the graphs, i think it's just an issue of a swift class compilation, that started showing when i added the swift code in my Objective-C project, but i just can't figure out which is it!

Comment: I have same problem. Specially the transition between views becomes super slow. Have you got any solution?