# Rules for type check in Swift builds?

Tags: swift, build-time

I’ve wanted to speed up my build times, so one of the steps was using `Other Swift Flags` and

```
-Xfrontend -warn-long-function-bodies=100
-Xfrontend -warn-long-expression-type-checking=100
```

But I’m not really sure how type checks work. For example, here’s a simple func for creating `random CGFloat`. Type check for it is over 200ms

```
static func randomColorValue() -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(Int.random(in: 0...255))/255.0
}
```

But on changing to something like this

```
  static func randomColorValue() -> CGFloat {
         let rnd    = Int.random(in: 0...255)
         let frnd   = CGFloat(rnd)
         let result = frnd/255.0

         return result
     }
```

or like this

```
static func randomColorValue() -> CGFloat {
     let rnd    : Int     = Int.random(in: 0...255)
     let frnd   : CGFloat = CGFloat(rnd)
     let result : CGFloat = frnd/255.0

     return result
 }
```

type check is still over 200ms.

What's wrong here? Is there any set of rules and best practices for dealing with build times? 
My Mac is a bit older (2012), maybe that's the problem?

EDIT:

After turning off `-warn-long-function-bodies` problematic line appeared, and that is

```
CGFloat(rnd)
```

It appears that casting `Int` to `Float`, `Double` or `CGFloat` shows slowing down of 150ms.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is Swift compile time so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25537614/why-is-swift-compile-time-so-slow)

Comment: Does `Int.random(in: Int(0)...Int(255)` and `frnd / CGFloat(255.50)` speed it up at all?

Comment: Isn’t the problem the literals like 0...255?

Comment: Thanks, tried it all, but no luck. See edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `warn-long-function-bodies` is unsupported ([it was added as an experimental flag](https://github.com/apple/swift/commit/18c75928639acf0ccf0e1fb6729eea75bc09cbd5)). If you remove it, I find that the expression time is often reported as twice as fast, which makes be believe that using the two measurements together is causing interference. Measurement takes time, too. `warn-long-expression` is a supported option.

Comment: Thanks, this answer helped partially.